# Can Monero incorporate Shamir's Secret Sharing?

Tags: shamirs-secret-sharing

Can the Monero code incorporate Shamir's Secret Sharing?

Comment: Where were you thinking that this could be incorporated? (Link to Shamir's Secret Sharing Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing)

Comment: It would require a dealer, so it wouldn't make a good multisig solution.

Comment: Do you mean as kind of multi-sig or as a way to split your backup to trusder parties?